# Matrix transposition from IO

Tags: haskell

I have a problem, user inputs number m (meaning matrix has m-rows, m-columns), then the matrix is read from stdin. I want to transpose the matrix and then output the matrix back on the screen in the same format.
for example:

Main> main
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

Anyway, I got somewhere in the middle, but i dont know how to parse the [[Int]] back to IO, so it can be print on the screen.

here is my code:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

transpose :: [[a]]->[[a]]
transpose ([]:_) = []
transpose x = (map head x) : transpose (map tail x)

readMany :: Read a => IO [a]
readMany = fmap (map read . words) getLine

parse :: IO ([[Int]])
parse = do
        [m] <- readMany
        xss <- replicateM m readMany
        let matrix = transpose xss
        return (matrix)

main :: IO ()
main = do     
          parse
          ??    --
          print ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to *extract* the value you parse:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  matrix <- parse
  ...
  print ???
```

Now, what's the type of `print`?

```
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

Well, `[[Int]]` is an instance of `Show`, so we can treat print as a specialisation of its type:

```
print :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
```

So, in fact, it's as simple as filling in the list we want to print in place of the `???`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  matrix <- parse
  print matrix
```

However, this prints the data out in the same way that GHCi does. If you want to print the data out in a custom format, you want:

```
putStr :: String -> IO ()
```

Let's say you write a function to format the matrix the way you want into a string:

```
formatMatrix :: [[Int]] -> String
```

This makes the complete program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  matrix <- parse
  putStr (formatMatrix matrix)
```

The difference between `foo <- bar` and `let foo = bar` is that the former extracts the result of an IO computation, while the latter just gives a name to a value.

So basically, the answer is that you don't need to put anything *into* IO to do this, since all the functions that create IO actions to do things like print strings out take *pure* values. This doesn't make them limited to printing the results of completely pure computations, however, since you can *extract* values from previous IO computations, and then feed them in to the printing functions as pure values. (In fact, this is the essence of monads, and why Haskell uses them to model IO in the first place!)

Comment: thanks it works, im trying to figure out the formatMatrix function  `formatMatrix :: [[Int]] -> String`, I would use `show :: Show a => a -> String`  and something like this `formatMatrix x = map show x `. Are my ideas correct?

Comment: Adams: Well, `map show` will turn an `[Int]` into a `[String]`, where each String is the decimal representation of the integer. `unwords` will turn a `[String]` into a `String`, separating each element with a space. And unlines will turn a `[String]` into a `String`, separating each element with a line break. Those should help you define `formatMatrix`; if you need more help, it's probably best to ask another question :)

Comment: Ah, just saw your edited comment. `map show x` will produce a `[String]`, since you're applying `show` to each `[Int]` element, producing a list of Strings. `map (map show)` should be your starting point.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure why that would happen. I recommend posting it as a new question so that somebody else can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to do exactly what you ask for, but sometimes it is just a little bit easier to make the string and then print it. In this case it is in fact very easy. All you need to know are the two functions `words` and `lines`, and their inverse `unwords` and `unlines`.

Here is a possible solution to your problem (note that I don't check that the inputs are integers and that I use the `transpose` from `Data.List`)

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

main = do
  n <- liftM read getLine
  xs <- replicateM n getLine
  putStrLn (unlines . map unwords . transpose . map words $ xs)
```

since `replicateM n getLine` gives us a list of lines, what `lines` would have done to the entire input, we are just sandwiching `transpose` in between `map words . lines` and its inverse.